# Create a copy of Material animation data

Tags: python, linked-data, data-blocks

I have several objects sharing a material that is animating. I'm able to create copies of the material and assign them to each object, but the animation data is still the same for all materials (see **.blend**, attached). How can I create a copy of the animation data associated with the material as well?

```py
import bpy

s_objs = bpy.context.selected_objects

for obj in s_objs:
    material_slots = obj.material_slots
    for mat_slot in material_slots:
        material = mat_slot.material
        new_material = material.copy()
        mat_slot.material = new_material

bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

I also tried adding this, but `animation_data` is `None`

```py
anim_data = material.animation_data.copy()
new_material.animation_data = anim_data
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Copying the `NodeTree`'s action seems to work:

```py
import bpy

s_objs = bpy.context.selected_objects

for obj in s_objs:
    material_slots = obj.material_slots
    for mat_slot in material_slots:
        material = mat_slot.material
        new_material = material.copy()
        new_material.node_tree.animation_data.action = material.node_tree.animation_data.action.copy()
        mat_slot.material = new_material

bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```